# DetailsView not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview add a link button "Edit":

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" text="Edit" CommandName="Select"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (var dataContext = new NewsStandAloneDataContext(Config.StandaloneNewsConnectionString))
            {
                DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
                DetailsView1.Visible = true;
                var dataList =
                    dataContext.sp_Name(Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.SelectedValue), Value1);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "show1", "openEditWindow();", true);
                DetailsView1.DataSource = dataList;
                DetailsView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
```

But my details view does not show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code you have two different methods in play.  In your ViewDetails button you are referencing a command name and argument.  In your other block of code you are responding to the changing of the selected row.  Two different concepts.

You would want to show the details view from the "ItemCommand" event, and not the selectedindexchanged event.